# Can the Flutter widget's build method be invoked multiple times while the widget itself is instantiated only once?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently investigating whether it's advisable to declare variables inside or outside the build method. To determine the practical benefits of declaring variables outside the method, I've been exploring scenarios where a widget is instantiated once, but the build method is called multiple times.

Upon thorough examination, I haven't come across any instances where this behavior is observed. In all cases I've observed, the widget's constructor is called first, followed by the build method.

Are there any benefits declaring variables outside the build method except code clarity and readability? and are there any cases that build method alone can be called multiple times with no constructor followed?

```
// outside build method
class Something extends StatelessWidget {
    int milliseconds = 1000;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Text('example...');
    }
}

// inside build method
class Something extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        int milliseconds = 1000;
        return Text('example...');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `build` method can (potentially) be called 60 times a second on a 60Hz device.  Flutter does a very good job of rebuild avoidance though, so widgets are only rebuilt when necessary.

Take the example counter app, and add a `print` statement in the `initState` and `build` methods.  You'll see that the state is only created once (at widget creation), and the `build` method is called every time the value is changed and `setState` is called.